# Solr - Ability to import from Redis?

Tags: solr, redis

I have a number of Celery tasks that are extracting text for indexing in a Solr server.  I've already written the DataImportHandler configuration for importing from a MySQL database.  The number of workers going on is more than enough to swamp Solr's insert query handling, and therefore results in a good number of timeouts.

However, is it possible to import the data from a Redis database?  I can insert into a Redis db server without a problem. I've looked throughout and the only apparent option is to use the POST query for update documents.  In other words, I'd have to write another task to pull from Redis and import into Solr, albeit at a slower rate than the original text extraction.